# Create Multiple Circles with a For Loop

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a method that makes a circle with size, and color.

```
public static void createCircle(int cx, int cy, int r, byte[][] inArrayr, byte[][] inArrayg, byte[][] inArrayb, int red, int green, int blue){    
    for (int i = 0; i < inArrayr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < inArrayb[0].length; j++) {
            if( ((i-cx)*(i-cx))+((j-cy)*(j-cy)) <= r*r){
               inArrayr [i][j] = (byte) red;
               inArrayg [i][j] = (byte) green;
               inArrayb [i][j] = (byte) blue; 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then to call this method I use:

```
BWandColorCircles.createCircle(100, 100, 100, rByteData, gByteData, bByteData, 255, 255, 230);
```

I want to put this method in a for loop but because rByteData, rByteData, rByteData are declared as byte[][] in my main method it gives me an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hint: I removed the $ from public and from that class names. No idea why you put them there - but they dont belong there!

Comment: Show the code that gives the error, and the error message.

Comment: It just says cannot find symbol and if i run it it doesn't give any error message. and the code is:
BWandColorCircles.createCircle(100, 100, 100, rByteData, gByteData, bByteData, 255, 255, 230); (error in rbytedata,gbytedata, bbytedata)